# read the data line by line from text file and then assign the value to the corresponding field in a structure

Tags: perl

I am beginner in Perl scripting.

I want to read the data line by line from text file and then assign the
value to the corresponding parameter into a structure

my_input.txt

```
filed_ind 0x0B uint8.unsigen int
tx_offset 0x0C uint8.unsigen int
rxpowe    0x0D uint8.unsigen int
fillers   0x0A uint8.unsigen int
cellid    0x12 uint8.unsigen int
cellnum   0x13 uint8.unsigen int
```

Encoding:

I want to assign each of values to their corresponding parameter 
(for e.g.filed_ind-> 0x0B ) it will be more like creating structure.

```
structure ABC
{
 filed_ind 0x0B 
 tx_offset 0x0c 
 rxpowe    0x0D 
 fillers   0x0A 
 cellid    0x12 
 cellnum   0x13 
}
```

Decoding:

from structure I want to extract the values in an array like my_message
(for e.g. my_message [0x0B,0x0c,0x0D,0x0A,0x12,0x13])

my code is given below

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $file = 'my_input.txt';
 open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
  while (my $line = <$fh>) 
  {
   chomp $line;
   my @strings = $line =~ /([a-z_A-Z_0-9-]+)/;                     
   foreach my $s (@strings) 
   {
    print "$1\n";
   }
 }
```

I was try to extract the vales from text file above code works only for extracting the parameter. what I ma looking for that I want the generate a structured message from text file which is like encoding and again extract the values from message structure like decoding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your question is not clear , below code stores [ox0B,ox0c,ox0D,ox0A,ox12,ox13]
into my_message .

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::IxHash;

my %hash;
tie %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';

my $file = 'my_input.txt';
open my $fh, $file or die "died opening $file";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if(length($line) > 1) {
        chomp $line;
        my @a = split(" ", $line);    
        $hash{$a[0]} = [$a[1], $a[2], $a[3]];
    }
    else {
        next;
    }
}

my @my_message;
foreach my $v (keys %hash) {
    push @my_message, $hash{$v}[0] ;
}
```

Comment: error:Use of uninitialized value $a[0] in hash element at test3.pl line 14, <$fh>

Comment: you need to format your input file or handle blank lines

Comment: fillers1{2}  { 0x00, 0x00 }       Uint8,unsigned char  
  n312_conn     0x02               Uint16, unsigned short , if the value start with Curly brackets how to remove curly brackets and value type is uitn16 then I need to pad with 0x00 (0x00,0x02) ..thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want to do. But this code loads the data you're interested in into a Perl hash (which is the closest thing Perl has to a struct) and then displays it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %struct;
while (<DATA>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split;
  $struct{$key} = $val;
}

say Dumper \%struct;

__DATA__
filed_ind ox0B uint8.unsigen int
tx_offset ox0c uint8.unsigen int
rxpowe    ox0D uint8.unsigen int
fillers   ox0A uint8.unsigen int
cellid    ox12 uint8.unsigen int
cellnum   ox13 uint8.unsigen int
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fillers' => 'ox0A',
          'tx_offset' => 'ox0c',
          'cellid' => 'ox12',
          'rxpowe' => 'ox0D',
          'filed_ind' => 'ox0B',
          'cellnum' => 'ox13'
        };
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply what I understand from your code that you are dumping the structure but If I want to modify some structure parameter again I have to go back to text file this will take more time so I want to modify in perl script itself. the output is not sorted