# Unable to extract expected value through map function in perl

Tags: perl

Not getting expected output for below input lines.

Basically what I am doing is I am extracting hex values and values inside curly braces.

1. The values inside curly braces should be appended with 0x0 (eg 0x01)
2. The value with uint16 should be splited for e.g(0x27,0x89)
3. The negative value -116 I want to take 8C 
     since its type is sint8 (for e.g -116--Hex is FFFFFF8C-->8C)

I am using `map` function for doing this, but I am getting output as some unexpected value.

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
while (<DATA>) 
{               
    my (@matches) = /(?|(0x[\dA-F]+)|(?:\{\s*|\s)(-?\d+)(?!x))/g;
    #print "@matches\n";
    push @data, ($1);
}

{
    my $data = join ',', map "0x0$_", map { unpack '(A2)*' } @data;     
    print $data, "\n";    
}

__DATA__     
meas_command    PHY_MEAS_CONFIG { 0}    meas_command        
UE_position_meas_flag   else { 0}   UE_position_meas_flag       
reporting_interval  MCFE_L1C_RPTPERIOD { 1} reporting_interval      
fieldIndicator  tdd neighbor cell measurement indicator { 2}    fieldIndicator      
Reserved1   0x00    Uint8,unsigned char     
my_info    0x2789  Uint16, unsigned short        
filler1{3} { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char     
rscp_tap   -116    Sint8,signed char              
rch_type    PCH { 7}    Uint8,unsigned char 
last_report 0   zeroth bit      
no_sync 0   oneth bit
```

Expected output:

```
 0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x27,0x89,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8c,0x07,0x00,0x00
```

What I was getting is:

```
0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00x,0x000,0x00x,0x027,0x089,0x00x,0x000,0x0-1,0x016,0x07,0x00,0x00
```

Something wrong is going with `map` function.
Please help me ?

Comment: I think the problem lies in your regular expression, not in the `map`.

Comment: through regex I am able to extract all the values but in map function it add 0x00x.

Comment: If you do `say for map { unpack '(A2)*' } @data` it will get clear what the problem is I think. You'll need to `use feature 'say';` to do that. Or simply look into `@data`. That should be enough. The `unpack` splits stuff into groups of two chars. That's weird.

Comment: I don't understand which numbers from the input you want. What about the `-116`? In your expected output, if we go backwards, we have `0x00` which maps to `no_sync`, then `0x00` and `last_report`, and `0x07` and `rch_type`. But then there's `0xFF` and nothing matching. The next one is three times `0x00`, which fits to `filler1{3}`. The `-116` gets ignored, but there's a `0xFF` in there. So do negative values always map to `0xFF`? Next is `my_info   0x2789`, which in your output gets split in half to `0x27` and `0x89`. You need to [edit] and clarify the behaviour this is supposed to have.

Comment: I have tried to use say map { unpack '(A2)*' } @data I am not getting expected output.

Comment: @simbabque negative value -116 should be converted to hex (FF8C) and I need only LSB of one byte (FF) and filler1{3}. I am unable to match with regex.

Comment: I think you should maybe create a more specific parser. The initial problem is definitely the regex. Sobrique's answer below explains what I was trying to say in greater details. If your input only contains the format that you showed, I suggest to print it to paper, take a red (or blue, you decide) pen and mark every value you want. Then write down what you want to convert that value to. Next, create a regex for each line, and a matching conversion. If you think that's too much code, you can still optimize, but it will at least work.

Comment: *"the negative value -116 I want to take first byte of LSB"* What do you mean by  the "first byte of least-significant byte"? Decimal -116 as a 32-bit integer is 0xFFFFFF8C. If it were -76,151,387 it would be 0xFB760531. Which of those bytes do you want?

Comment: Is there really a space at the beginning of every line in your data file and your Perl program file?

Comment: The code that you show won't even compile. You would get something like `Global symbol $fh requires explicit package name`, so it cannot possibly generate the output that you label *What I was getting is*. Why do you think it's a good idea to do anything but copy and paste your code into your question? All I can think is that you're hiding some nastiness that you don't want us to see, which may well be the reason for your problem. You are getting advice for free here; please don't play games and make us work harder than necessary to get the truth out of you.

Comment: This `(?: \{ \s* | \s )` means a left brace `{`, followed by zero or more space characters or a space character. What do you mean here?

Comment: @Borodin for negative value -116 I will be storing LSB of 8C since its type is sint8 .and there is a space for beginning of each line.

Comment: @Borodin (?: \{ \s* | \s ) I wanted to capture values inside { }

Comment: @Borodin shall we have discussion over chat ..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126147/discussion-between-abhishek-and-borodin).

Comment: That data is too irregular to extract the information needed. For example, what's the type (`Sint8`, `Uint16`, etc) for `meas_command    PHY_MEAS_CONFIG { 0}    meas_command`???

Comment: This question is far too broad. SO is not a code writing service. You have encountered numerous problems, but you didn't ask about any of them; you simply asked for working code. That's not acceptable. You should ask about each problem individually and precisely. (And you shouldn't ignore [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39709638/589924) when you do! [Twice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39682057/589924) you've been shown to use `hex`, but your code does not include any use of `hex`!)

Comment: @ikagami sorry  this was my last post ..Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

It's not your map command, it's your regex.

Your captured data in this code is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '0',
          '0',
          '1',
          '2',
          '0x00',
          '0x2789',
          '0x00',
          '-116',
          '7',
          '0',
          '0'
        ];
```

If you then:

```
my @newdata =  map { [unpack '(A2)*'] } @data;
print Dumper \@newdata;
```

Then what you get is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '0'
          ],
          [
            '0'
          ],
          [
            '1'
          ],
          [
            '2'
          ],
          [
            '0x',
            '00'
          ],
          [
            '0x',
            '27',
            '89'
          ],
          [
            '0x',
            '00'
          ],
          [
            '-1',
            '16'
          ],
          [
            '7'
          ],
          [
            '0'
          ],
          [
            '0'
          ]
        ];
```

Which hopefully gives an insight into what's wrong? The `unpack` operation is returning a list when you do it, and even if it didn't - you're capturing some values with leading `0x` and others without.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a history of some of your questions about this same problem

The issue seems to be primarily that you are struggling to define your problem, and secondarily that you don't know Perl

No one here can help you to define your problem, and while it is a dreadful approach just to keep trying different approaches, you are welcome to do that to yourself in your own time

The secondary problem is that you don't know Perl, and as you're using some very low-level concepts you have had to repeatedly invoke help to even get started in your "throw pasta until it sticks" methodology

You must go away and

- ***Define your problem properly.*** No guesses. Look at all of the data that you could possible get and write down a specification for data that your program will handle, and—most importantly—insist that *it won't handle anything else* unless you are engaged to modify your code
- ***Learn the Perl constructions*** that you're using. Never, ever, guess what they might do and throw them into your program in the hope of getting lucky

  With `unpack`, for instance, start with strings like `'0A0B0C'` and `"\x01\x02\x03"` and work out how to pack and unpack them. Try *every* format specifier in several different ways until you are confident that you could predict the result of any call

  I believe that the Perl documentation on `pack` and `unpack` is poor (not least because `unpack` is defined in terms of `pack`, and there are too few examples) but the answer is to *try things* that you believe the documentation says should work

Whatever you do, endless questions like this, that you hope may get you to a working program, regardless of whether you understand how it works, are anathema to good programming practice

If you write your program by guesswork and release it when it seems to work, then a few months later someone will come to you saying that there is a problem with this thing that you wrote. They will point to a line and ask, "Why did you put that in there? What does it do? How does it work?" and you will feel such a fool saying that you have no idea: you just copied it from the internet

It's also worth remembering that employers don't like software "copied from the internet" as, outside the realm of open software, they may be taken to court at any time if the source can be proven to be plagiarized

If you want to write software then please [learn Perl properly](http://learn.perl.org/). If you would prefer to do something else then please, go and be a botanist or a spaceman. But for goodness sake stop copying code from the internet and telling people that you're a programmer: you're someone who copies from the internet, and that isn't a real profession

16-Sep-2016
[*read the data line by line from text file and then assign the value to the corresponding field in a structure*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530793/read-the-data-line-by-line-from-text-file-and-then-assign-the-value-to-the-corre)

23-Sep-2016
[*extracting hex values from line in perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652838/extracting-hex-values-from-line-in-perl)

23-Sep-2016
[*command line replacement with new value not working*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665410/command-line-replacement-with-new-value-not-working)

26-Sep-2016
[*separating array elements every 4 characters in array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703642/separating-array-elements-every-4-characters-in-array)

27-Sep-2016
[*Trouble extracting specific information from log file*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721606/trouble-extracting-specific-information-from-log-file)

27-Sep-2016
[*matches happen but replacement not happening*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728295/matches-happen-but-replacement-not-happening)

29-Sep-2016
[*unable to extratct the values through regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773287/unable-to-extratct-the-values-through-regex)

30-Sep-2016
[*How to do multiple value replacement in a multiple line at one time*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798083/how-to-do-multiple-value-replacement-in-a-multiple-line-at-one-time)

18-Oct-2016
[*how to pass one regex output to another regex in perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102877/how-to-pass-one-regex-output-to-another-regex-in-perl)

19-Oct-2016
[*Unable to extract expected value through map function in perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132199/unable-to-extract-expected-value-through-map-function-in-perl)

Comment: Also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39678809/589924) from a different account (which actually has a working solution, from when the input data was still parsable).

Comment: That is disputably a different author. I shall leave my post as it is, as I say that this is *some of your questions*

Comment: It's hard to identify the values to convert and the type into which to convert the value (e.g. `7` should become `0x07` if the type is `Sint8`, or `0x00, 0x07` if the type is `Uint16`), and sometimes the type isn't even present. I believe they are trying to build a "packed" structure, but from incomplete definitions in an undefined language.

Comment: "I believe that the Perl documentation on `pack` and `unpack` is poor" - Have you looked at [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)?

Comment: @DaveCross: I have, and it fulfils a need, but it is a tutorial. I think there should be an accessible reference as well. Along similar but very unrelated lines, the field specifiers in `strptime` / `strftime` only seem to be listed alphabetically everywhere (they're not documented at all in `Time::Piece`) and I have written my own chart that orders them into century, year, month, week, yearday, monthday, weekday, and time fields. I find it much more useful, and may do something similar for `pack`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output, there are two pieces of information you need to extract from each line:

1. The values to convert.
2. The type into which they should be converted (e.g. `Uint16`).

For example, `7` should become `0x07` if its type is `Sint8`, or`0x00,0x07` if its type is `Uint16`, so you need both the value (`7`) and the type (`Sint8` or `Uint16`).

Currently, you aren't even trying to extract the type, You say you are having problems doing the conversion, but that goes without saying since you don't have all the information you need to do the conversion!

Unfortunately, the format of the data is inconsistent, unclear and/or incomplete. Extracting the necessary information from that data is not something reasonably achievable. (For example, what type should be used for the `0` in `meas_command PHY_MEAS_CONFIG { 0 } meas_command`?) Until you fix your data to be something parsable, your efforts are doomed to fail.

Once you have achieved that, you've already been shown how do the conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682057/589924).